# Getting 3087 error

Tags: php, opayo

I'm getting the following error when trying to build a SagePay Form integration.

```
3087 : The SuccessURL format is invalid.
```

The url being sent is in the following format 
    http://sub.domain.co.uk/folder/

The documentation for the field says..

> This should be the fully qualified URL (including http:// or https:// 
>   header).
>   It is the URL of the page/script to which the user is redirected if the 
>   transaction is successful. You may attach parameters if you wish. Sage 
>   Pay Form will also send an encrypted field containing important 
>   information appended to this URL (see below).

As far as I can tell the SuccessUrl I am sending is perfectly valid & fully qualified.  Am I missing something simple?

```
$mySage->addFieldToCrypt("SuccessURL", 'http://sub.domain.co.uk/folder/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ping test on real success url.

The Success URL needs to be accessible. Ensure you are not adding an index to it. Make it as generic as possible.

We recommend, when you get this error to check the following:
*Must be a dynamic success url.  *Make sure the URL is available at the time of the transaction. 
*Is the URL on a shared server? i.e. are there mutliple sites processing high volumes of transactions that may effect the transaction for you. *Ensure the server handle the workload.
*Try accessing your IP from a seperate device. *Check ports 80 and 443 are open.

Your example is http. Make sure there are no external https elements appended to the success page.

Comment: The SuccessURL field must contain a Fully Qualified Domain Name and page reference pointing to the externally visible page on your site which your customers can be returned to if a transaction succeeds.  This URL must be http:// or https:// and be less than 255 characters long.  Check your code to ensure that you only use a fully qualified URL.